# How can I do after refresh page nz-checkbox show double checkbox

Tags: angular

I use angular-cli and nz-zorro-antd on the first load this checkbox show normal and then I refresh page the checkbox show like that please help.

[nz-checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcbEm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Please inspect your checkbox after reloading. I think another label is adding which have rendering other checkbox style on second time when you reload your page.